# Download specific kernels for distros

Tags: linux, download, kernel, centos

I am running CentOS 5.3. I am wondering where I can download the latest kernel for this distribution.

I went to www.centos.org but could see any kernel download only the complete distribution is available to download. I just want the kernel.

Kernels on the www.kernels.org are the vanilla kernels. I am wondering where to download for the specific distro?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest CentOS kernel is available through the yum repositories. Just type `yum update` in a terminal as root. It will not be the same version as on Kernel.org as CentOS runs on the same kernel as RHEL which sticks with a proven kernel for a while (but back-ports security fixes if necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to download the kernel to compile it myself. The reason for this is just experimenting in configuring and compiling. However, I didn't want to use the vanilla kernels as they are just the basic source code that distros take and add their own features too. I was looking for the updated kernel for 5.3. Thanks.

Comment: @ant2009: use your package manager to grab the source package for the kernel.